# Converting dictionary of list to csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
dictionary = {'number': [2.1607142857142856, 1.5160021597156612, 1.0, 6.0],
              'orbital_period': [847.5717667678571, 1796.522108459915, 0.73654, 14002.0], 
              'mass': [2.89239793814433, 4.4152433928281205, 0.0036, 21.42], 
              'distance': [39.760093457943924, 50.97704197461588, 1.35, 354.0], 
              'year': [2007.4732142857142, 5.01701576965303, 1995.0, 2013.0]}

zd = zip(*dictionary.values())
with open('file.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(dictionary.keys())
    writer.writerows(zd)
```

How do I read this file back to see if I get the desired output? Will this even give me the output

I want the output to have the attributes in the first column and the list of numbers as the row:

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your desired output looks like?

Comment: i want it to appear as a 5x5 table

Comment: Do you want this output in the same order: number, orbital, mass, etc. or no?

Is @Chris' answer in a format that is acceptable?

Comment: What's your question here? How exactly did this not work?

Comment: im not getting an output

Comment: @dmb What is the output your expecting, include that in the post ?

Comment: i have described the output now in my original post. hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good time to look at pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {'number': [2.1607142857142856, 1.5160021597156612, 1.0, 6.0],
              'orbital_period': [847.5717667678571, 1796.522108459915, 0.73654, 14002.0], 
              'mass': [2.89239793814433, 4.4152433928281205, 0.0036, 21.42], 
              'distance': [39.760093457943924, 50.97704197461588, 1.35, 354.0], 
              'year': [2007.4732142857142, 5.01701576965303, 1995.0, 2013.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

To read it back in

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
```

The dataframe will look like this

```
     number  orbital_period       mass    distance         year
0  2.160714      847.571767   2.892398   39.760093  2007.473214
1  1.516002     1796.522108   4.415243   50.977042     5.017016
2  1.000000        0.736540   0.003600    1.350000  1995.000000
3  6.000000    14002.000000  21.420000  354.000000  2013.000000
```

Comment: `pandas` is absurd overkill for something like this, especially since the OP already has working code, AFAIKT

Comment: i want to do it without panda and I want the attributes to be in the first column

Comment: Overkill for sure.  No harm in learning more than one way to achieve the desired output, especially if some sort of data manipulation is in the future for this user, these basic functions would prove useful.